# How to handle OUTER JOIN like functionality in CosmosDB?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a query that uses JOINS to query my Cosmos Data, the query looks as follows

```
SELECT c.id, c.ItemLevel, c.ItemNo, bv.variantId, bv.variantDescription AS title, c.BasicData.presentation.articleLongDescription[0] AS Description, c.BasicData.presentation.articleCompositionList.origin, bv.size.sizeName, c.DetailedData.locales[0].images ?? c.BasicData.asset.assets[0].locations[1].path AS images, 'SE' AS country, 'SEK' AS currency, 'en' AS language, l.categories AS categories, c.PriceData.WhitePrice, c.PriceData.RedPrice, c.PriceData.DiscountPercentage, c.PriceData.TypeOfDiscount
FROM c
JOIN bv IN c.BasicData.base.sales.variants
JOIN l IN c.DetailedData.locales
WHERE c.brand = 'XXX'
AND l.country = 'SE'
AND l.language = 'en'
AND c.ItemNo = 'XXX'
AND c.Season = 'XXX'
AND c.Consumer = 'XXX'
```

This query will work as long as my JOINS have data, but if for example c.DetailedData is NULL then it will not return anything.

How can I make it return whatever the available data is and just leave out the ones that do not exist.

I know I can use c.foo ?? c.bar but that only works if the property exist not if the entire object used in a JOIN is not there.

This JOIN question is regardless of document structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my experience,`Left Join` is not supported in cosmos db. Obviously, one dataset join an empty array ,the result is an empty dataset,you only could get nothing! This is not relational database.

1.https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a08a8029-1bd7-4e70-8408-ddb6e268d9ac/left-join-in-azure-cosmosdb-sql-api?forum=azurecosmosdb

2.https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/37949650-support-left-join

So,i'm afraid you have to query the data separate between `BasicData` and `DetailedData` then try to merge the data as you want.

Or you could use transmission tool(such as ADF) to flatten the cosmos db data into sql db.So that you could use relational db sql as normal.